# Timestamp in Sharepoint external content type not matching value in SQL table

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sql-server-2008-r2, bcs

I have an external content type in SharePoint 2010 pulling data from a SQL 2008R2 DB using BCS. All the data comes back fine but the Time stamp column is off by 2 hours when I compare the values displayed in the Read List with the values returned when I query the DB in Management Studio. I've attached a picture with an example:

[image: Example]

The times displayed in the browser are 4 hours earlier than the Time stamp returned by Management Studio. I've checked the Date and Time settings on both the client and server and they are fine. Any ideas what could cause this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the normalisation settings for your BDC.

Make sure you set it like this:

```
<TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.DateTime"
 Name="YourDate" DefaultDisplayName="Your Date">
 <Interpretation>
  <NormalizeDateTime LobDateTimeMode="Local" />
 </Interpretation>
</TypeDescriptor>
```

http://www.shillier.com/archive/2010/09/01/why-are-my-date-fields-wrong-in-business-connectivity-servces.aspx

Comment: I messed it up on the first attempt, this actually does do the trick

Answer (score 0):

External Systems created through BCS use UTC as the time zone by default. Your SQl database inherits the time zone settings from Windows so crosscheck the server settings with you External Content Type properties and also your front-end SharePoint settings. Depending on you settings, if your user profile has a specified time zone, the time is converted from UTC to the user's time zone. If the time zone has not been specified (default) the time zone of the site on which the External Data is hosted is used.